# Db2 load status

Tags: shell, unix, db2, db2-luw

I am using the following statement in Unix script to load the table in DB2. The command was success but still  `echo $?` is returning 2. Could  anyone clarify why it is returning 2?

```
db2 "load client from  /user/abc.ixf of IXF insert into EMP NONRECOVERABLE";
```

`echo $?` is returning 2.

Comment: You should check that from the documentation but apparently return code 2 means _DB2 command or SQL statement warning_.

Comment: Thanks for input.return code 2 means DB2 command or SQL statement warning. where to get that information.I am unable to get that information.could you please provide any url on this

Comment: I googled _db2 load return value_.

Answer (score 2):

The exit-code 2 represents a WARNING, so the load completed successfully but either at least one line from the file being loaded had some issue that you may want to check (data truncation, data conversion etc) *OR* there was some operational issue ( e.g. a resource constraint limited the number of resources available, or the tablespace(s) are in a certain state etc.). Much depends on your context.

To find such things, you should use the **MESSAGES** option and specify a file relative to your client where Db2 can record such information. You can then read or parse that text file to get more details.  Consider using also the **WARNINGCOUNT** option to for Db2 to return an error if more than your-specified number of warnings happen.

See the [documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0008305.html) for your Db2-version.